# Qt Offline OSM Map freezes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, qt, offline, sdk

I am developing an application that needs to show map tiles without internet. My initial step is to show map tiles, that part is done. Next step is to show tiles without internet. I tried to get tile images from my local directory but program stuck on the beginning and reading tiles from the given directory. What should I do? Should I serve my tiles on a local server? Or what is the best way to work at offline mode.

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtLocation 5.8
import QtPositioning 5.2
import QtGraphicalEffects 1.0

Item {
    height: 1080
    width: 1920
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Plugin {
            id: plugin
            name: "osm"
            PluginParameter{
                name: "osm.mapping.offline.directory"
                value: "MAP_TILE_PATH"
            }
        }

        Map {
            id: maps
            anchors.fill: parent
            plugin: plugin
            gesture.enabled: true
            gesture.acceptedGestures: MapGestureArea.PinchGesture | MapGestureArea.PanGesture
                                      | MapGestureArea.FlickGesture
            gesture.flickDeceleration: 3000
            focus: true
            zoomLevel: 10
            center: QtPositioning.coordinate(41,30)
            minimumZoomLevel: 1
            copyrightsVisible: false
            onCenterChanged: {
                console.log(maps.center)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what Qt version? i believe this was a known issue, resolved in latest Qt5 releases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution is that (using currently) serve your tiles in local http server and pass the url of your server to the ***osm.mapping.providersrepository.address*** parameter.

```
PluginParameter{
    name:"osm.mapping.providersrepository.address"
    value: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In qt source code you may change the wildcard symbol to the file formats of your tiles.

```
https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtlocation.git/tree/src/plugins/geoservices/osm/qgeofiletilecacheosm.cpp?h=dev#n158
```

```
const QString fileName = tileSpecToFilename(spec, QStringLiteral("*"), providerId);
```

then you need to recompile Qt.